# AssertionError testing arrays with Mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I have what I thought was a pretty uncontroversial test to make sure my initial testing setup is working ok.

```
import assert from 'assert';
describe('Test', () => {
  it('Arrays', () => {
    assert.equal([], []);
  });
});
```

The output of the test is pretty mysterious to me.

```
> mocha --compilers js:babel-register test/*_test.js

  Test
    1) Arrays

  0 passing (29ms)
  1 failing

  1) Test Arrays:

      AssertionError: [] == []
      + expected - actual

      at Context.<anonymous> (basic_test.js:6:12)

npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Adjectives fail me.
Is there someone who can shed a little light on this.

Comment: `[] !== []`? 2 objects are not equal. String representation of those arrays are equal. Since the returned values are 2 _primitive_ strings: ` [].toString() === [].toString()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe `assert.deepEqual()` is what you are looking for?

```
assert.deepEqual([], []);
```

Alternatively, you could use the [should.js library](https://shouldjs.github.io/):

```
require('should');

var a = 'test';
a.should.equal('test'); // "equal" for primitives

var b = [];
b.should.eql([]); // "eql" for data structures
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd hardly call that an uncontroversial test, in what javascript test framework is `[]` equal to `[]`? Because in vanilla javascript, it definitely isn't.

```
[] == []
false

[] === []
false
```